# How to get Youtube Video URL from catchphrase using javascript/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, youtube

I want to get the first video from youtube which is listed when I enter a certain catchphrase, e.g. when I enter 'Kill You Eminem' it should give me the URL for the first video, in this case 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1I1x2pYMK0'.

I want to achieve this using javascript/node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the YouTube API to obtain data. Just use axios or the fetch api to create a get request to their endpoint and get the first item of the return array. Here is the complete documentation of YouTube's API. If you need help with the code, HMU in messages.

Here is sample for getting the most viewed videos:

```
GET {base_URL}/search?part=snippet
                     &forMine=true
                     &order=viewCount
                     &type=video
```

Here is the whole documentation of YouTube's API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests